# Workflow to create daily report

Tags: workflow, custom, object

I am trying to create a workflow, or another creative way through salesforce, to keep track of my daily 'excused absences'.

Our clients have their kids enrolled in our programs. I am developing a sort of attendance system to keep track of all excused/un-excused absences. For the excused absences, I have a fillable form on a visualforce page that parents can fill out, and it will create a new record for my Excused Absence object based on Contact Name(Lookup), date, and reason. I want the teachers to be able to access a report from their Salesforce that can pull up every student that has filled out an excused-absence form for that particular day.

**My question is, is their a way to configure a workflow to automatically create daily reports compiled of Excused Absence records sorted by date?**

Ex: Everytime a family fills out an excused absence form for july 27th, there should be a July 27th report that is composed of all students that have filed an excused absence form for that day.

Note: I am trying to make it easily accessible to my teachers that aren't so Salesforce friendly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can auto-run your Report everyday to a certain time by using Future Schedule on the Report you create and have it Emailed to the users.  To do this Create a report and provide the necessary conditions and after saving your report, Click on the drop down for Run Report and select Future Schedule and there you can choose you're options for daily/weekly/monthly.

Comment: Or you can create a Workflow on Excused Absence object and provide a Formula Criteria isNew(), and select Email alert Workflow action and in the Email provide a URL which takes you to the Report. So in that way you can track the Excused Absence in real time.

Comment: why not put a custom link on the sidebar 'called 'Today's Excused Absences' and have it link to a report that is prebuilt with a absence_date__c = TODAY filter?